# Change default admin password on WSO2 DAS

Tags: passwords, wso2, admin, wso2-das

After installing WSO2 Data Analytics Server and changing the default admin password i am getting the following ERROR

```
    ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
-  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7711 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
    org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7711
```

Does anybody knows why this is happening. What conf file i have to change and how?

```
stack trace:

    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-01 09:06:19,010] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator}
-  wrong userName or password {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator}
    TID: [-1] [] [2016-08-01 09:06:19,013] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
-  Thrift Authentication Exception {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
    org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Thrift Authentication Exception
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:94)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: ThriftAuthenticationException(message:wrong userName or password)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:1394)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:88)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:46)
        ... 7 more
    TID: [-1] [] [2016-08-01 09:06:19,015] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
-  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7711 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
    org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7711
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Thrift Authentication Exception
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:94)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: ThriftAuthenticationException(message:wrong userName or password)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:1394)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:88)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:46)
        ... 7 more
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-01 09:06:29,070]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-08-01 09:06:29,070+0300] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
    TID: [-1] [] [2016-08-01 09:06:48,893]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup} -  No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup}
    TID: [-1] [] [2016-08-01 09:06:48,927]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge}
    TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-01 09:06:48,932] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator}
-  wrong userName or password {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator}
    TID: [-1] [] [2016-08-01 09:06:48,933] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
-  Thrift Authentication Exception {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
    org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Thrift Authentication Exception
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:94)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: ThriftAuthenticationException(message:wrong userName or password)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:1394)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:88)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:46)
        ... 7 more
    TID: [-1] [] [2016-08-01 09:06:48,935] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
-  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7711 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
    org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7711
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Thrift Authentication Exception
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:94)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: ThriftAuthenticationException(message:wrong userName or password)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:1394)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:88)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:46)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: Please post the steps you followed to reproduce the error. I´m using a fresh DAS 3.0.1 instance, change the admin password, restart the server and no problems.

Comment: How did you changed the admin password?

Comment: I changed the password through web interface

Comment: You changed the admin password and you dont have any errors to your log file? I have to mention that i can login in the web interface. But i am getting this error to my log file

Comment: I have the same problem on EI 6.1.0(integrator+analytics). After change the password from management console of Integrator(without restart) I see the same error on Integrator log. On the Analytics log I see the following error: `TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-22 16:51:31,219]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin connected {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge}
... ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator} -  wrong userName or password {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator}
`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for sharing the stack trace. The logs show ThriftAuthenticationException(message:wrong userName or password) this means that even though the admin password is changed via the UI that some places are still referring to the default password.

If we are publishing events into DAS from ex: API Manager 1.10.0. If the admin's password has been changed on DAS, then on the other products(ex:api manager) we need to specify the new password where ever the  as well as the admin
and admin are given such as in api-manager.xml

When we grep for port 7711 within the DAS pack the matrix.xml is also having admin as the password as a result could you kindly change the password on the relevant areas and check again.

regards,shavantha

Comment: He meant the METRICS.XML file not matrix.xml

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways to change the password. However, 
1.We can change the password by updating the admin-password via user-mgt.xml or via the web interface as mentioned by you

The below document has the guidelines that will help you change the password
https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Adding+and+Managing+Users+and+Roles

However, appreciate if you can provide the following answers to try and reproduce your scenario
1.Did this error prevent you from logging in after the attempt to change the default password
2.Can you please share the full stack trace for the error.
3.What is the Operating system and JDK version are you using

Comment: The answer in your first question is No. I can log in without any problems. About 2 i just posted the full trace bellow.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode) And Debian Jessie Operationg system

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the same error on EI 6.1.0 and EI 6.1.1 (Integrator and Analytics profile activated)
After the change of the admin password must be update this files for databridge comunications:

- EI_HOME/repository/deployment/server/eventpublishers/MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher.xml
- EI_HOME/repository/deployment/server/eventpublishers/MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher.xml

Set property *encrypted* to **false** and replace the encrypted old password with **not encrypted new password**

```
<property encrypted="false" name="password">NOT-ENCRYPTED-NEW-PASSWORD</property>
```

- /conf/log4j.properties
  Change the password for `log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.password`

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] Finally the problem was a sample carbon application that was deployed and was trying to connect with the default credentials. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

user-mgt.xml
UserManager->Password

repository/conf/log4j.properties

```
# DAS_AGENT uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.DAS_AGENT.layout=org.wso2.carbon.analytics.shared.data.agents.log4j.util.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.DAS_AGENT.columnList=%D,%S,%A,%d,%c,%p,%m,%H,%I,%Stacktrace
log4j.appender.DAS_AGENT.userName=admin

log4j.appender.DAS_AGENT.password=xxxxxxx
log4j.appender.DAS_AGENT.url=tcp://localhost:7612
log4j.appender.DAS_AGENT.maxTolerableConsecutiveFailure=5
log4j.appender.DAS_AGENT.streamDef=loganalyzer:1.0.0
log4j.logger.trace.messages=TRACE,CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE
```

Comment: please search 7612 or another port