# How to Solve Thrift Authentication Exception (wrong userName or password) in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-enterprise-integrator

In my local environment, I connect Wso2 analysis with Wso2. Everything is okay. When I change password property like below in MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher.xml and MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher.xml:

```
<property encrypted="false" name="password">my password</property>
```

WSO2 turns it encypted version and it worked, but when I did the same in my dev environment. It turns this property like below:

```
<property encrypted="false" name="password"/>
```

It deletes my password. Do you have any ideas why it happens?
I looked here, but it does not solve my problem. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642396/change-default-admin-password-on-wso2-das/50638175#50638175](http://here)

The Error:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2018-06-01 09:52:10,445]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup} -  No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-06-01 09:52:10,529] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Thrift Authentication Exception {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Thrift Authentication Exception
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ThriftAuthenticationException(message:wrong userName or password)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result$connect_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:2020)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result$connect_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:1998)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:1940)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:96)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:45)
    ... 7 more
TID: [-1] [] [2018-06-01 09:52:10,533] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} -  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Thrift Authentication Exception
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:93)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: ThriftAuthenticationException(message:wrong userName or password)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result$connect_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:2020)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result$connect_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:1998)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:1940)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:96)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:45)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my dev environment, I also get this error log when I changed the password property in MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher.xml and MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher.xml:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.util.EventPublisherConfigurationBuilder} -  Unable to decrypt the encrypted field: password in adaptor: MessageFlowConfigurationPublisher {org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.util.EventPublisherConfigurationBuilder}
```

wso2ei-6.1.1\conf\carbon.xml

In this file, our custom keystore is configured wrongly. I change this:

```
<KeyAlias>my Alias</KeyAlias>
```

then, it worked